# Grocery CRUD CodeIgniter - how to add link for each row .

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm triying to implement Grocery-Crud for codeigniter, and I didn't have troubles until i needed to add a link for each row in my table . . . I need to add a column with links to see the details of each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is `add_action`

read their documentation it shows how to use it [Documentation](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/add_action)